# What was cut from the Indian release of Deadpool?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, deadpool, deadpool-2016

Censor Board Of Film Certification (CBFC) has recently passed Deadpool for an Indian release with seven cuts.
<sub>~[source](http://www.dnaindia.com/entertainment/report-banned-in-china-deadpool-passed-in-india-with-7-cuts-2176246)</sub>

What were the seven cuts?

Comment: Is there anyway to get hold of the Indian versions of movies? (This might help the person who made that petition.)

Comment: Does it include an alternative cab driver with a comedy American accent?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From my own answer on [What are the 7 cuts made in Indian version of Deadpool?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47693/what-are-the-7-cuts-made-in-indian-version-of-deadpool) from Movies & TV:

> From [businessofcinema.com](https://businessofcinema.com/hollywood/ryan-reynolds-deadpool-gets-censored-in-india-fans-lash-out/286550), seven scenes that were cut by the
>   censorboard of India are:
>
> > 1. All the cuss words have been muted.
> > 2. The triple headshot scene has been deleted during the car chase fighting scene. Because it shows violence.
> > 3. All the nud* and love scenes have been deleted and some have been shortened.
> > 4. Hand cutting and gushing of blood of Deadpool has been replaced with the visuals of Stefan Kapicic’s character Colossus.
> > 5. The bare bodies in the stri* club have been replaced.
> > 6. The lady in poster touching her parts is replaced.
> > 7. All the gory shots in the climax scene are replaced too.
>
> Below is the official paper of the cuts made in film,
>
> [image]

After watching the film, I can say nothing will be missed from the story point of view, all the curse words are mute but rest is ok.

Comment: A very interesting look into a different culture than mine that I probably would not have been exposed to otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

According to an article in the *Hindustan Times*:

> "The DNA report suggests that the film was passed by the always-controversial censor board with just 7 cuts, and none of them are really that unexpected. **Most of the profanity is gone**. **References to male and female reproductive organs have been removed**. **A love-making scene has been shortened** as usual. **Shots of a head being blown and a hand being chopped off have been severed**. The same goes for a **scene at a strip club** where the amount of nudity has been greatly reduced."

([Source](http://www.hindustantimes.com/hollywood/ryan-reynolds-deadpool-cleared-by-the-censor-board-with-these-7-cuts/story-LedbZgdbEH8cDYlMSf476O.html) — emphasis mine)

Comment: All of that in just seven cuts? Impressive.

Comment: @ibid Impressive? It would be more interesting to know the _total length_ of the cuts, rather than their _number_! :-) (I haven't seen the movie, but from what I heard removing profanity would reduce it to trailer length)

Comment: @Ifurini even if they only focused on removing the profanity, I would imagine that there were more than *seven* expletives.